# After uninstalling ati fglrx drivers ubuntu 11.10 wont boot

Tags: 11.10, ati, fglrx

First off this site has been so helpful I've solved all my issues without even having to ask any questions but this time I'm stumped.

I uninstalled the ATI fglrx drivers because I was getting an issue after awhile if I opened any 3D programs (My game engine, Blender 3D. etc...) it would log me out and I'd have to restart my pc to be able to use them. Then after awhile the same thing again.

Well I figured since I had just reinstalled my ati drivers through the terminal beforehand that was the issue so I used the additional drivers program to uninstall it. Now when it boots black screens and every minute or so the monitors turn off then back on. Cant ctrl+alt+f1 or f2, etc... So I tried recovery mode and dropping to shell it cant open the cache or the I uninstalled the ati fglrx drivers dpkg because the read-only filesystem.

I'm stumped, please help?

Comment: Just to say that the GRUB recovery mode is read-only in 11.10, you have to select `remount` from the menu, and then you can get into a full access shell prompt.

Answer (score 4):

After booting to recovery mode select the option 'remount' as suggested in the comment above.
Drop into a root shell with internet acces ('netroot' option) and try executing the following commands to reset your graphics driver configuration to the ubuntu default drivers.

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge xorg-driver-fglrx fglrx*
sudo apt-get remove --purge fglrx*
sudo apt-get install build-essential cdbs fakeroot dh-make debhelper debconf libstdc++6 dkms libqtgui4 wget execstack libelfg0 dh-modaliases
sudo apt-get install --reinstall libgl1-mesa-glx libgl1-mesa-dri
sudo mv /etc/X11/xorg.conf /etc/X11/xorg.conf.old
sudo dpkg-reconfigure xserver-xorg
```

Restart your computer using

```
sudo reboot
```

And boot up normally

Or if you have installed the drivers manually from the binary download available on the amd website run these commands:

```
 sudo sh /usr/share/ati/fglrx-uninstall.sh
 sudo mv /etc/X11/xorg.conf /etc/X11/xorg.conf.old
 sudo apt-get install --reinstall xserver-xorg-core libgl1-mesa-glx libgl1-mesa-dri
 sudo dpkg-reconfigure xserver-xorg
 sudo reboot
```