# How to reset display settings in XFCE \ Ubuntu 12.04 and also flgrx drivers

Tags: 12.04, display, resolution, xfce, fglrx

I recently upgraded to Ubuntu 12.04 and since I hate unity I installed the Xubuntu package and am using XFCE instead.

Since I have a Radeon HD5770 I also installed the fglrx drivers.

This all went fine (aside from the fact that the post-release update fglrx drivers have an error on installation and Ubuntu thinks they're not installed when they actually are.

I configured my display settings (dual monitors, a 17" CRT on VGA and a 17" LCD on DVI) in the amdcccle program and everything was perfect.

THEN, 2 days ago, I accidentally clicked on the "Display" settings in XFCE "settings" manager.  After that, everything got screwed.

Now, I normally run the CRT at 1152x854 and the LCD at 1280x1024 with the CRT as my primary monitor (with panel) and the LCD without panels etc just to display other windows when I want to drag them over there.

The problem is now that if I set my CRT to 1152x864, it stays at 1280x1024 virtually and half the stuff falls off the screen.

It also puts the LCD at 1280x1024 BUT then overlays the CRT's display ontop with different wallpaper in an L shape down the right-hand and bottom edges.

In short, nothing makes sense and everything is FUBAR.

I tried uninstalling fglrx through synaptic, and renaming xorg.conf and also the xfce XML file that has monitor settings but it still won't make sense.

Unity on the other hand can currently set everything normally so the problem appears to be only with XFCE.

In any case, I can't even get the fglrx drivers back, when I re-installed them, I can't run amdccle anymore as it says the driver isn't installed!!

Can someone help me reset my XFCE settings so the monitors aren't screwed with some incorrect virtual desktop size and also so I can get fglrx drivers back and working? I really don't want to have to format and reinstall and go through all the hassle but it looks like I may have to :(

Answer (score 0):

Try following my answer on this question. [After uninstalling ati fglrx drivers ubuntu 11.10 wont boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/104799/after-uninstalling-ati-fglrx-drivers-ubuntu-11-10-wont-boot/119532#119532)
This will set all the display drivers back to their out-of-the-box state.
After you're done with all the steps try reinstalling the amd drivers.